# How to clear service and detected in subscribtion?

Tags: angular

I have clear method :

```
  clear() {
    //this.customerSearchData = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);
    this.basketData = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);
  }
```

And in my component i have this:

```
 this.sharedData.getBasketData().subscribe((data)=>{
            if(data['basket']){
                this.basket = data['basket'];
            }else{
                this.basket = {};
            }
        });
```

But when i call this clear its triggerd in clear method but in subscribe in my component not. Any suggestion?

Comment: This falls short of a [mcve], but note that the component is subscribing to *a specific subject*, not the general `basketData`. If you replace the subject, you will need to create a new subscription (and `.unsubscribe` the old one, otherwise there's still a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast the subject after clear using this.basketData.next();

Comment: its not trigger again

Comment: oh sorry, when you're doing this: this.basketData = new ReplaySubject<Object>(1);. your .subscribe is on a different object. thus it won't receive callbacks

Comment: so how can i fix that?

Comment: Just remove the data from the current object, don't re-assign it.

Comment: @Carsten so how do you *"remove the data"* that's already been emitted through a stream? You could flush with `null` or an empty object, but it makes no sense to un-emit something.